# How to style font size in Angular Material 12 Menu?

Tags: sass, angular-material

I have a simple menu:

```
 <mat-menu #menuA="matMenu" class="my-list">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let menuItem of ['Aaaa', 'Bbbb', 'Cccc']; let i = index">
     <button mat-menu-item class="list-item">
       <mat-icon>item</mat-icon>
       {{ i }} - {{ menuItem }}
     </button>
   </ng-container>
 </mat-menu>
```

I tried various approaches but I am not able to change the font size of the menu items.

```
.my-list {

  .list-item {
    font-size: 8px !important;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    line-height: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    .mat-icon {
      margin-right: 4px;
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried with and without:

```
::ng-deep .list-item {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

I also tried with and without:

```
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

No luck; any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`::ng-deep` is deprecated!

create a separate CSS file for the menu styles and importing it in your component so:

```
<mat-menu #menuA="matMenu" class="my-list">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let menuItem of ['Aaaa', 'Bbbb', 'Cccc']; let i = index">
    <button mat-menu-item class="list-item">
      <mat-icon>item</mat-icon>
      {{ i }} - {{ menuItem }}
    </button>
  </ng-container>
</mat-menu>
```

```
/* styles.css or your component's CSS file */
.my-list .mat-menu-item {
  font-size: 8px !important;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  line-height: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.my-list .mat-menu-item .mat-icon {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but font remains unchanged. If I remove:  mat-menu-item all works, but with 'mat-menu-item' the styles do not apply. Used to work with the previous versions ...